# Audio and Video capture from webcam using html5

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

I need some help/suggestion . I'm building a website using PHP, MySQL, HTML5, CSS and I'm stuck at a point.

I have few queries regarding Audio and Video capture from webcam using HTML5.

1. Is it possible to capture audio and video (Audio and Video means , audio separately, video which will record the audio too [for an example say some one is singing]) from webcam using html5 and PHP or JavaScript code and store it at local pc or in a Live servers pace where I want to ?
2. Also if it is not possible using html5 , can anybody please suggest a solution? May be using flash or some 3rd party application which I can use in my website with no restriction!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Info on HTML5 video/audio capture is readily available via Google. I would suggest that questions posted here are about specific problems that you have experienced while trying to implement something specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can rent a server with Flash Media such as www.influxis.com and develop the capture part using flash.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 supports getUserMedia, as documented at http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html

A good article on this (including examples that actually work, with code) is available here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/